# How to horizontally align text with images using flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to horizontally align text with three vertically aligned images on each side of the text. However, when I apply "display:flex;" to the parent element of the three, it changes the alignment of the three divs from vertical to horizontal, changes the size of the images and causes white space inbetween the first div and the text, rather than pushing all the divs to the left of the screen.

```css
.text {
  font-family: 'font', cursive; 
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 35em;
}

.image > img {
 width: 20%
}

.image {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
} 

.flex {
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class='image'>
   <img src='image.jpg'>
   <img src='image.jpg'>
   <img src='image.jpg'>
  </div> 

  <div class='text'>
   <p>text
   <br><br>text 
   <br><br>text
   <br><br>text</p>
  </div>     

  <div class='image'>
   <img src='image.jpg'>
   <img src='image.jpg'>
   <img src='image.jpg'>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your flex to your divs and remove the display and flex-direction from images

```css
.text {
  font-family: 'font', cursive; 
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  flex:0 0 10%;

}

 img {
 width: 100%;
}

.image {
 

 flex: 0 0 10%;
} 

.flex {
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class='image'>
   <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'>
   <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'>
   <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'>
  </div> 

  <div class='text'>
   <p>text
   <br><br>text 
   <br><br>text
   <br><br>text</p>
  </div>     

  <div class='image'>
   <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'>
   <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'>
   <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, helped a lot, and worked how I wanted it to.

Comment: @tocky glad that this helped you np  so plz if you can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```css
.text {
  font-family: 'font', cursive; 
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.image > img {
 width: 20%;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.image {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column nowrap;
} 

.flex {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
 align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class='image'>
   <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'>
   <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'>
   <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'>
  </div> 

  <div class='text'>
   <p>text
   <br><br>text 
   <br><br>text
   <br><br>text</p>
  </div>     

  <div class='image'>
   <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'>
   <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'>
   <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Is that good?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this code but there is still white space between the first and second flex item and no white space between the second and last flex item. I'm thinking that it might have something to do with the code above it.

Comment: @tocky Editted again. Is that better?

Comment: Yes, thanks heaps. No longer that unwanted white space and works how I wanted it to.